# update_facts with json_query

Tags: json, ansible

I am attempting to modify several values in a JSON file. The most efficent way to do this seems to be with the update_fact module which requires an ouput to the register. This issue I am having is I need to run a json query to find the data I need to modify.

When I attempt to modify the json file with update_fact I would like to use teh json_query inside a single update_fact block so I don't have a recursive register name that I have to get rid of at the end but every time I try this ansible tells me
 `msg: 'template error while templating string: unexpected char ''?'' at 40. String: {{ jsondata.stigs[0].rules| json_query([?group_id==V-256376].comments)}}'`

Is there a better way to do this without having to try and break the JSON file completly apart, modify each section and try and put it back together. The ultimate goal of this is to modify a bunch of the vaules and output it to a file.

my playbook

```
  tasks:
    - name: Read file directly into fact
      set_fact:
        jsondata: "{{ lookup('file', './files/U_VMW_vSphere_7-0_ESXi_V1R2_Manual_STIG.cklb') | from_json}}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test.stigs[0].rules|json_query(query)}}"
      vars:
        groupid: 'V-256376'
        query: "[?group_id=='{{ groupid }}'].discussion"
      register: v256376

    - name: update IP address
      ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.ip_address
            value: "10.10.10.10"
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.host_name
            value: "{{ esxserver }}"
          - path: "{{ jsondata.stigs[0].rules| json_query([?group_id==V-256376].comments)}}"
            value: "this worked" 
      register:  jsondata
```

**Edit adding mre for follow up question**

checklist json file stripped down to 2 examples

```
    {
      "stigs": [
        {
          "rules": [
            {
              "group_id": "V-256375",
              "status": "not_reviewed",
              "comments": "",
              "finding_details": ""
            },
            {
              "group_id": "V-256375",
              "status": "not_reviewed",
              "comments": "",
              "finding_details": ""
            }
        }   
      }
```

The purpose of this is to take the JSON file, which is a check list of things and run it against servers to see if the settings are correct, then take a copy of those settings and output it back to the JSON file as evidence that they were set correctly. Long way to say this is for STIG validation.

For each group_id I will need to make an API call to check then change teh status field  to either open or not_a_finding then fill in the comments/finding_details with what the output of the API call was.

The idea is to update the varible to
`gid_comments['V-256375']: "The UserVars.HostClientSessionTimeout is set to '{{ UserVarsHostClientSessionTimeout }}'"` or `gid_comments['V-256375']: "The UserVars.HostClientSessionTimeout is set to 900"` without the varible in it, then use the orginal question to put that back into the JSON file so it can be opened and read by security people.

So the follow up question becomes how do I dynmaically add things to the `gid_comments['V-256375']` field since ansible dosn't seem to like varibles with a `-` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) YAML data for testing (the format is not important)

```yaml
shell> cat files/stig.yml
target_data:
  ip_address: 10.10.10.99
  host_name: server
  stigs:
    - rules:
        - group_id: V-256376
          comments: comments for gid V-256376
        - group_id: V-256377
          comments: comments for gid V-256377
```

Read the file

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        jsondata: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/stig.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  jsondata:
    target_data:
      host_name: server
      ip_address: 10.10.10.99
      stigs:
      - rules:
        - comments: comments for gid V-256376
          group_id: V-256376
        - comments: comments for gid V-256377
          group_id: V-256377
```

---

Q: ***"Update_facts with json_query."***

From your query(below), it can be seen you want to update *comments* for *group_id* equal to V-256376 in the *rules* of the first item in *stigs*

```yaml
- path: "{{ jsondata.stigs[0].rules|
            json_query([?group_id==V-256376].comments) }}"
  value: this worked
```

A: It is not possible. The parameter [path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#parameter-updates/path) says:

> It should be a valid Jinja reference.

The result of your *json_query* is not a valid Jinja reference. Instead, you can create a structure with the update(s). For example, a dictionary

```yaml
  gid_comments:
    V-256376: this worked
```

and use it to update the facts. Create the list you want to update

```yaml
  stigs_0_rules: |
    [{% for i in jsondata.target_data.stigs.0.rules %}
    {{ i|combine({'comments': gid_comments[i.group_id]|d(i.comments)}) }},
    {% endfor %}]
```

gives

```yaml
  stigs_0_rules:
  - comments: this worked
    group_id: V-256376
  - comments: comments for gid V-256377
    group_id: V-256377
```

Now, use the list *stigs_0_rules* to update the facts

```yaml
    - ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.ip_address
            value: 10.10.10.10
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.host_name
            value: esx-server
          - path: jsondata.target_data.stigs.0.rules
            value: "{{ stigs_0_rules }}"
      register: update
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  update.jsondata:
    target_data:
      host_name: esx-server
      ip_address: 10.10.10.10
      stigs:
      - rules:
        - comments: this worked
          group_id: V-256376
        - comments: comments for gid V-256377
          group_id: V-256377
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    gid_comments:
      V-256376: this worked

    stigs_0_rules: |
      [{% for i in jsondata.target_data.stigs.0.rules %}
      {{ i|combine({'comments': gid_comments[i.group_id]|d(i.comments)}) }},
      {% endfor %}]

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        jsondata: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/stig.yml')|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: jsondata

    - debug:
        var: stigs_0_rules

    - ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.ip_address
            value: 10.10.10.10
          - path:  jsondata.target_data.host_name
            value: esx-server
          - path: jsondata.target_data.stigs.0.rules
            value: "{{ stigs_0_rules }}"
      register: update

    - debug:
        var: update.jsondata
```

Comment: Sorry about that with the comments. I have updated the orginal question and deleted my question comments. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second part of the question.

Comment: I am not sure how to say it better without going into a long disertation with lots of examples that arn't mimiual. But i think I found a solution for it. Thank you for the help

Comment: There is always a minimal example if you can isolate the problem. You're welcome.